# Getting an objects name during instantiation

Tags: python

Is it possible to acquire the name of an object and store it an object upon creation?  i.e if I were to create a new class..

```
Class foobar():
    pass
```

And then say...

```
fooinstance = foobar()
```

Is there a way to store the name 'fooinstance' in the created object of type foobar?  Can **name** be used to implement this behaviour?

The reason I ask, is that the created Object will be creating additional objects whom need to know 'who' they were created by.

Comment: There is no "who", there are only references.

Comment: How can the reference of the object A that instantiated object B be passed to object B during instantiation?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Sounds like you want to get circular references and a memory leak.What is the ultimate goal?

Comment: This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13445512/creating-a-connection-object-in-python) to my initial stack overflow question illustrates the ultimate goal.

Comment: Ah, it sounds like you are wanting something like [networkx](http://networkx.lanl.gov/). Basically, you can create a factory method in the class that then holds a reference to the child object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to do something like this?

```
class Player(object):     
    # ... snip ...

    def fire(self):
        bullet = Bullet()
        bullet.owner = self
        bullet_list.append(bullet)
```

I've used something similar, when you need to know the parent or owner. If the owner may possibly not exist, you could use a weakref.

Answer (score 2):

No. And it would be meaningless regardless.

```
fooinstance = foobar()
bar = fooinstance
print bar.__name__
```

Find another way to identify your objects, perhaps with a key set in the initializer.

Comment: To clarify the intent, I've edited my question.  The fooinstance will be creating objects which needs to know 'who' they were created by.  I would prefer not to have to have it once in the assignment, and again in defining the key value as I think it makes it less readable.  Is there a different way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to know "who" created an object, then just pass that "who" in at creation time:

```
class Foo():
  def __init__(self,whichbar):
    do something with whichbar

class Bar():
  def something(self):
    myfoo = Foo(self)
```

Note that the *name* of the variable that an object is assigned to is immaterial -- that name changes as the object is passed between routines. It's the actual instance you care about.

Comment: Thanks, that answers the question.  I've given monkey the check though just based on who answered first.